# Posicionar un input en el centro de un contenedor

Tags: html, css, input

¡Hola! Tengo el siguiente codigo CSS:

```
.container-input input {
    width: 50%;
    height: 28px;
    background: #555555;
    color: aquamarine;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-bottom: solid 2px aqua;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Este es el codigo html (no se para que puede servir, pero me recomendaron agregarlo):

```
<div class="container-input">
            <h2 class="h2-input">League of Legends</h2>
            <p class="p-input">TEXTO</p>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lol ?>">
            <p class="p-checkbox">Mostrar</p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check-lol" selected>
        </div>
```

Basicamente, quiero posicionar un input en el centro de un container, pero el margin auto no funciona no se porque razon, ¿Como puedo hacer que un input se posicione en el centro de un contenedor?
No me den la respuesta de poner "margin-right: 200px; margin-left: 200px" porque es terrible para un modelo responsive.

¡Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: No se cual es la necesidad, ya que es por css, pero bueno, agregado :D

Comment: @SilviaManquis el HTML nos permite revisar si las reglas de CSS se están aplicando correctamente, imagina que en tu CSS tienes algo como `.miclase` pero en tu HTML tienes `<div id="miclase">`. Si conoces un poco, sabrás que hay un error. Y es solo 1 ejemplo de muchos errores que se pueden presentar

Comment: Si, mi error fue no colocar que todo funcionaba menos eso jaja, igual ya lo solucione ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un contenedor para centrar solo el input que necesitas.  Algo asi:

```css
.container-input input {
    width: 50%;
    height: 28px;
    background: #555555;
    color: aquamarine;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-bottom: solid 2px aqua;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container2-input {   
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-input">
            <h2 class="h2-input">League of Legends</h2>
            <p class="p-input">TEXTO</p>
            <div class="container2-input">
              <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lol ?>">
            </div>
            <p class="p-checkbox">Mostrar</p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check-lol" selected>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

me salio asi, espero te sirva:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>League of Legends</h1>
    </div>
    <div>TEXTO</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lol ?>" />
        <p class="p-checkbox">Mostrar</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check-lol" selected />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}